# Anyone encounter the ecs agent changing file permissions on the containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker, chef-infra, amazon-ecs

We're using the ECS Agent container on Ubuntu 16.04.  The services' containers all start correctly and have the correct file permissions internally; the `Dockerfile` for each container creates a user called `app` for better security.

Somewhere along the way the file permissions inside the containers are changed to `root:root` which causes the app to stop functioning.

Has anyone encountered this?

Here's the code which creates the ECS agent.  It's a chef recipe.  Does any of the below look off to anyone?

***Note** : the same set of services are installed on an ECS Optimized instance (which is of course based of Amazon linux) and all works fine.  So it's not an app related issue.  We are forced to move to Ubuntu by the security team.

```
platform = node['platform']
env = node.chef_environment

docker_image 'amazon/amazon-ecs-agent'



ENVIRONMENT = [
 'ECS_LOGFILE=/log/ecs-agent.log',
 'ECS_DATADIR=/data/',
 'ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true',
 'ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE_NETWORK_HOST=true',
 'ECS_CLUSTER=devops2',
 'ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["json-file","syslog","awslogs"]',
 'ECS_AGENT_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=/etc/ecs/ecs.config',
 'ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg',
 "ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA=#{node['common']['ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA']}"
]

VOLUMES = [
  '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock',
  '/var/log/ecs:/log',
  '/var/lib/ecs/data:/data'
]

# start the container and map it to port 8484
docker_container 'amazon-ecs-agent' do
  repo 'amazon/amazon-ecs-agent'
  tag 'latest'
  network_mode 'host'
  restart_policy 'on-failure'
  env ENVIRONMENT
  volumes VOLUMES
  action :run_if_missing
end
```

Comment: I have not worked on chef, but can point one thing. If a new folder gets created by your image on host mounted volume then it would be under the root user in most cases. Because your app user won't exist on host. Please check if this is the case

Comment: @TarunLalwani Many thanks! Question: why would that change existing directories' permission? Does it only effect new directories?

Comment: Only new ones not existing.

Comment: The is on existing files in the container.